# Change dataframe from MultiIndex to MultiColumn

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like

```
multiindex1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a'], np.arange(3, 8)])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=multiindex1)
multiindex2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['s'], np.arange(1, 6)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=multiindex2)
multiindex3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['d'], np.arange(2, 7)])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=multiindex3)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
>>>
            0         1         2
a 3  0.872208 -0.145098 -0.519966
  4 -0.976089 -0.730808 -1.463151
  5 -0.026869  0.227912  1.525924
  6 -0.161126 -0.415913 -1.211737
  7 -0.893881 -0.769385  0.346436
s 1 -0.972483  0.202820  0.265304
  2  0.007303  0.802974 -0.254106
  3  1.619309 -1.545089  0.161493
  4  2.847376  0.951796 -0.877882
  5  1.749237 -0.327026  0.467784
d 2  1.440793 -0.697371  0.902004
  3  0.390181 -0.449725 -0.462104
  4  0.056916  0.140066  0.918281
  5  0.164234 -2.491176  2.035113
  6 -1.648948  0.372179  0.600297
```

Now I want to change it into multicolumns like

```
                              a                             b                             c
          0         1         2         0         1         2         0         1         2
1       Nan       Nan       Nan        ...
2       Nan       Nan       Nan        ...
3  0.872208 -0.145098 -0.519966        ...
4 -0.976089 -0.730808 -1.463151        ...
5 -0.026869  0.227912  1.525924        ...
6 -0.161126 -0.415913 -1.211737        ...
7 -0.893881 -0.769385  0.346436        ...
```

That's to say I want two goals to be done:

1. change level0 index(multi index into single index) into level0 columns(single column into multi column)
2. merge level1 index togather and reindex by it

I've tried `stack` `unstack` `pivot`, but couldn't get the target form.
So is there any elegant way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work for me.  I used to work with someone who was amazing with multi-indices and he taught me a lot of this.

```
df.unstack(level=0).reorder_levels([0,1], axis=1).swaplevel(axis=1)[["a", "s", "d"]]
```

Output:

```
          a                             s                             d                                                                                                     
          0         1         2         0         1         2         0         1         2                                                                                 
1       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.206957  1.329804 -0.037481       NaN       NaN       NaN                                                                                 
2       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.244912  1.880180  1.447138 -1.009454  0.215560  0.126756                                                                                 
3  0.871496 -1.247274 -0.458660  0.514475  0.989567 -1.653646 -0.623382 -0.799157  0.119259                                                                                 
4 -0.756771  0.523621  0.067967  1.066499 -1.436044 -1.045745  0.440954 -1.997325 -1.223662                                                                                 
5  0.707063  1.019831  0.422577  0.964631 -0.034742 -0.891528  0.891096 -0.724778 -0.043314                                                                                 
6 -0.140548 -0.093853 -1.060963       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.643902 -0.062267 -0.505484                                                                                 
7 -0.449435  0.360956 -0.769459       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```